# What is happening in Python 3 when I call list() on an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I want to print out a board for tic tac toe that is initially

```
board = [[0]*3]*3
```

I want to use map to apply print() to each row, so that the output is

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

In Python 3, map returns an iterator instead of a list, so an example of adapting to this I found is

```
list(map(print, board))
```

Which gives the correct output. But I don't know what's going on here - can someone explain what is happening when you do

```
list(iterator)
```

?

Comment: **Don't do this.** Use a loop. `map` is for applying a transformation to data, not for causing side effects.

Comment: Also, `[[0]*3]*3` is the wrong way to initialize that board. All the sublists in that board are the same list; it'll break as soon as you try to do anything with it, such as `board[0][0] = 1`. Use a list comprehension: `board = [[0]*3 for i in xrange(3)]`

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `list` constructor is a common way of forcing iterators and generators to fully iterate in Python. When you call map, it only returns a map object instead of actually evaluating the mapping, which is not desired by the author of your code snippet.

However, using `map` just to print all the items of an iterable on separate lines is inelegant when you consider all the power that the print function itself holds in Python 3:

```
>>> board = [[0]*3]*3
>>> board[0] is board[1]
True
>>> "Uh oh, we don't want that!"
"Uh oh, we don't want that!"
>>> board = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> board[0] is board[1]
False
>>> "That's a lot better!"
"That's a lot better!"
>>> print(*board, sep='\n')
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

**Additional Note:** In Python 2, where `print` is treated as a statement, and is not so powerful, you *still* have at least two better options than using `map`:

1. Use a good old for-loop:

`for row in board: print row`

2. Import Python 3's print function from the `__future__` module:

`from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list(map(print, board))
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[None, None, None]
```

When you call `list` on an iterable, it extracts each element from the iterable.  In this case, a side-effect of that is that the three rows are printed.  The result of the `print` operation, though, is `None`.  Thus, for each `print` performed, a `None` is added to the list.  The last row above, consisting of the three Nones, is the actual list that was returned by `list`.